# Doctrine result cache is not deleting in production environment in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine-orm, memcached

I am using Doctrine result cache in symfony2.

only in production environment doctrine result cache delete is not deleting cache.
but in development environment result cache delete is work fine.

here is code which i have written to use result cache in doctrine.

```
//code to store result cache in doctrin. 
$qb->useResultCache(true);
$qb->setResultCacheId('key');    

//code to delete result cache when db data edit.

$em->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl()->delete('key');
```

here problem is with production environment in symfony2.

Is there any special doctrine cache configuration for production environment?

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be any special flag for the production environment. Doctrine even doesn't care about the environment, that's particularly Symfony2 stuff which is set when the kernel is initialized, for example:

```
#web/app.php
...
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

Maybe first check:

```
echo $this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment();
```

to be 100% sure you're in the 'prod' environment.

Then if you are, you might try:

```
$em->getConfiguration()->getResultCacheImpl()->deleteAll();
```

to check if it would delete all the cache for the the environment so you will know if it's a particular problem with the delete('key') method or it's something else.

Comment: I have check environment it is 'prod' only and tried to delete all cache also but still it was not deleting in production environment.